# Is there a text snippit manipulator plugin or feature in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

So I was writing some code in which a lot of the code could be generated by transforming some text containing a list of items into Java code.  Transforming the text using regular expressions seem to do the trick.  So I wrote three regular expressions than when applied in order would transform my list of items into the code I wanted.

The problem was, is that I had to transform about twenty of these lists into twenty different classes.  This morning I thought, "I wish there was some sort of plugin for eclipse where I could write a short Perl script store it into a button, then highlight some text, then have that Perl script manipulate and replace the highlighted text.  I could then build a library of common text manipulators that would save me a bunch of time."

Does anything like that exist?